# Styles on a class added by ClassList isn't working

Tags: javascript, css

My code seems to be fine, when I console.log the class name it shows that the class is added, but the styles are not working. It was working just fine before but idk what triggered this problem now.
Any help would be appreciated!

JS code:

```
let maxAmountMessageTimeoutId;
// Max Amount Added Message Visibility
export function displayMaxAmountMessage(productId) {
  const maxAmountMessage = document.querySelector(`.js-max-amount-message-${productId}`);

  maxAmountMessage.classList.add("max-amount-message-visible");

  if (maxAmountMessageTimeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(maxAmountMessageTimeoutId);
  }

  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    maxAmountMessage.classList.remove("max-amount-message-visible");
  }, 2000);

  maxAmountMessageTimeoutId = timeoutId;
  console.log(maxAmountMessage.className);
}
```

CSS code:

```
.max-amount-message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.max-amount-message-visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I tried putting the function in the main file, and put "let maxAmountMessageTimeoutId;" before the click event listener out of scope as a global variable but nothing I try works. If I delete the line "let maxAmountMessageTimeoutId;" then the message appears but invokes errors and clearTimeout doesn't work obviously.

Comment: You haven't given us enough to go on here, but it's possible that you added some CSS that has a higher priority than the CSS in that class so those styles no longer apply when you add it. Inspect the relevant element in the browser devtools to see what styles are applied to the element.

Comment: What you need to do is use the DOM inspector tool to select that message block as the current "active" element. Let the code run, and the inspector will show you the effective CSS rules for the element. What you want to look for is how the "opacity" value is set. If it's not set to 1, then some other rule somewhere is affecting the style for the element. As suggested elsewhere, your debugging will be a lot easier if you boosted the timer duration for testing.

Comment: The thing is, in the console it shows that the class is added. But when I use the inspector tool, it does not show the added class, only the old default class. I increased the milliseconds, I even removed the setTimeout just to see if the class will be added. But the result is the same: displaying in console but not in the dev tools. This piece of code was working perfectly fine before and i haven't changed any css since, I have no clue what's going on lol

Comment: Then at least test it _by manually adding the class in the elements panel_ and seeing if your styles apply.

Comment: Note that the "DOM Inspector" is **not** "View source". You want to be looking at the right-hand side of the Inspector window, where the browser will show you all of the style blocks that apply to the element. (You may have to adjust the view to be able to see enough information.)

Comment: yea i know that haha. it only shows the styles of the old default class even tho according to the console the new class is added. I even removed setTimeout so that it won't disappear. I think the code is fine, probably my vs code's live server is bugging. I tried closing and opening everything but alas

Comment: This question does not provide a clear picture to solve the actual problem. The OP's answer and the problem asked are misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem lol. Apparently my code was fine here, the problem resided elsewhere in my code.

```
// Increment Quantity Button
  document.querySelectorAll('.increment-quantity-button')
    .forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const {productId} = button.dataset;

        
        updateSelectorValue();
        renderHeader();
        renderCheckoutTitle();
        renderOrderSummary();
        incrementCartQuantity(productId); // Contains the function displayMaxAmountMessage()
      });
    });
```

I originally put the `incrementCartQuantity(productId)` above all those functions.
All those "render" functions basically refresh the html on page, so I guess the message I wanted to display wasn't displayed bcuz of the refreshing, altho I expected to at least see a glimpse.

It didn't occur to me the order of funcs would matter here lol